# does .net Ftpwebrequest use the native windows ftp client?

Tags: .net, ftpwebrequest

I want to know if the .net Ftpwebrequest class internally uses the native windows ftp client. Or does .net framework has a client of its own?

Comment: What do you mean by "native windows ftp client"?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Perhaps the ftp.exe

Comment: Yes, ftp.exe in the System32 directory.

Comment: @NageshK Then the response is no. It would be stupid *and* slow *and* more complex.

Comment: @xanatos: Thx. So, .net framework has its own FTP client? The reason I ask this is that we are moving our web server to Cloud and we want to understand if there will be any impact to the FTP functionalities being handled in .net code.

Comment: @NageshK I don't know if calling it a "client" is the right term. It is a library. Let's say that it is independent from any external program.

Comment: @xanatos: Thx for clarifying. So, is it a right statement if I say that irrespective of the Windows OS version and physical server topology (stand alone/VM/Cloud), my .net Ftpwebrequest works the same?

Comment: I'm sorry if I used any wrong terminology. But I hope the question is clear

Comment: @NageshK It is wrong :-) Because sadly the ones that invented the `ftp` protocol were sadist... A "normal" protocol is like http: the client connects to the server and the data is transmitted back and forth. Client-side firewall normally lets connection out without problems, server-side firewall knows that there is a server inside, so accepts connections. Ftp can work in two ways, active and passive. In active mode (the default), the client connects to the server that then opens another connection back to the client :-) http://www.slacksite.com/ftp.html

Comment: @NageshK So: *irrespective of the Windows OS version* **true**, *physical server topology (stand alone/VM/Cloud)* **false**

Comment: @xanatos: Thx for clarifying. So, in my case what should I analyze to confirm that my FTP code in my .net application works fine when we move to cloud? Assuming that we have taken care of firewall restrictions, if any

Comment: @NageshK If there aren't problems with firewall/NAT/network topology/certificates/... then there should be zero problems.

Comment: @xanatos: Thx a lot for all the assistance. So, to answer my initial question to the point: .net Ftpwebrequest does not use the windows native ftp process (ftp.exe present in system32). Will you place this as answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `FtpWebRequest` doesn't use any external tool to create ftp connections. It uses quite "standard" Windows API to do it: if you look with ILSpy at

```
FtpControlStream.CreateFtpDataSocket(FtpWebRequest request, Socket templateSocket)
```

you can see that it uses `new Socket(...)` to create the data socket.

You can then follow the call chain to

```
FtpControlStream.CreateFtpListenerSocket(...)
FtpControlStream.BuildCommandsList(...)
CommandStream.SubmitRequest(...)
FtpWebRequest.TimedSubmitRequestHelper(...)
FtpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(...)
```

and finally to the

```
FtpWebRequest.GetResponse(...)
```

that you probably use.